# How get correct DPI information on linux?

Tags: x11, dpi

system: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

The default Resolution is 1280x720, the DPI is 96.

When adjust the 'fractional scaling' is 125%, I have two options to get the DPI:

Use the command: `xrdb -query |grep dpi`

the DPI is `192` ??!

```
Xft.dpi:    192
```

Use the command: `xdpyinfo`, the DPI is `120`.

```
screen #0:
  dimensions:    2048x1152 pixels (433x244 millimeters)
  resolution:    120x120 dots per inch
```

Why the two commands return different DPI ?

When scaling to 125%, Why the dimensions is 2048x1152 ? (2048/1280 = 1.6, 1152/720 = 1.6)

Is the X11 API is wrong or other problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking neither `xrdb` nor `xdpyinfo` are the right place to query the screen's pixel density.

`xrdb` shows you a DPI value, since it's the place where one can (but is not required to!) set a overriding DPI value for Xft, and some desktop environments to, just "because". `xdpyinfo` shows mostly values that already did exist waaay back in the original X11 core protocol, where one could also specify physical dimensions of a screen. The problem is, that on modern systems, which are capable of dynamically attaching and removing displays, things are done through *XRandR* and the capability to drive multiple *X11 screens* on the same *X11 display* no longer is used (it's all just one large X11 screen now). So depending on how you configured your monitors, the values reported by `xdpyinfo` are off.

To arrive at the correct pixel density, one must use XRandR (CLI query/set tool name is `xrandr`) to retrieve information about the physically connected displays. However be advised that it is perfectly possible for several displays of different pixel density to show overlapping regions of the X11 screen, and within those regions there's no unambiguous DPI value available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It seem likes use 'xrandr' is the most reasonable option now?

Comment: I have a question about 'xrandr'.  When use the 'xrandr', why the dimensions is also '2048x1152' , the fractional scaling is 125%?  Get the dimensions from 'DisplayWidth' ?

Comment: @hyt: I can't tell you exactly what's going on, but I'd assume that the pixel framebuffer is scaled up to the next power of 2 for efficiency reasons and then the DPI value reported to applications slightly reduced to compensate for the overscaling. To be honest, everything – and I mean really *everything* – about HiDPI support on any OS out there is a wild hodgepodge of crude kludges. I'd not be surprised if the values you're reading there are the result of broken program logic somewhere in the DEs display configuration utility.

Comment: I have another question: If the aforementioned， when scale factor is 125% or 150, query the dpi with command 'xrdb -query', the 'Xft.dpi'  is always 192.  If I understand correctly, the 'Xft.dpi' means the 'font' scaling capability, is not the screen's scaling capability.  When query the dpi with the command 'xdpyinfo | grep B2 resolution',  the dpi is 120 and 144.  This dpi can be seen as the screen scaling capability. Could we understand it this way?

Comment: @hyt: The value of `Xft.dpi` stored in the X resources (which is what you query/set with `xrdb`) is an *override* value set by your desktop environment, that will later on be used by the *Xft* library to determine the rendering resolution of fonts. This value however is not set *directly* by properties your physical screens or the information accessible by `xdpyinfo` or `xrandr`. Instead *some* part of your desktop environment will set it, and the drive the value it sets from other parts of your system.

Comment: @hyt: In a way this may be seen as a form of *scaling*, but it's actually more of a kludge, rather than a clean solution.

Comment: It seems that using ‘Xft.dpi’ is not a good way to get screen DPI. We should use 'DisplayWidth*25.4/DisplayWidthMM' to calculate dpi, which is according to DPI definition ?

Comment: @hyt: Yes, this is the most accurate you can get. However always keep in mind that the reported physical screen size either might not be accurate or even not applicable. Video projectors for example don't have a fixed size. The next best thing would be angular resolution (i.e. dots per degree), however that depends on observer distance.

Comment: @hyt: To be honest, the only situation in which an actual reading of a display devices pixel density is sensible to use is, if you want to exactly reproduce dimensions in a document, i.e. a 12pt font in a PDF shall appear exactly 12pt on the screen.

Comment: @hyt: From a practical point of view, what most users do care about is how things appear in their field of view, and for that a couple of heuristics is far better suited: Assume that for ~3:2 aspect (vertical or horizontal) the typical observer distance will be about 1.5 to 2.5 times the diagonal. So for a widescreen display, fit a 3:2 rectangle in its center, and assume that the user observes it from about 2 times that diagonal distance. Take the number of pixels within those bounds and from that you get practical angular density of the pixels.